# How to update a ListViewItem in a ListView Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to update the text inside a ListViewItem but I can't find a way.

I modify the observable collection that I use but the ListView does not update. The only way I achieved it was by removing and adding the same item, but this creates an awful animation (which I removed, but it looks horrible too).

My model:

```
public class Feed : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int idfeed { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
    public string likes { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string iLiked { get; set; }
    public string next_id_comment { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Any sample code will help to figure out the problem. However make sure you have correct Binding implemented for the Model property you are trying to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the property of the item(model) thats bound to the listviewitem's textbox. Make sure the Model which contains the property implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Do it this way:

```
    private string message;
    public string Message 
    {
        get
        {
            return message;
        }
        set
        {
               message = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged("Message");
        }
```

then in the datatemplate add the property name.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I've already tried that. Thank you!

Comment: would be more helpful if you could post your code (the model).

Comment: Take a look now, I've added it. Thanks!

Comment: Now, is there a way to make this to every single property? (Without having to do it by hand)